# Calculating sum of values in point shapefile within moving window using QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, point, spatial-statistics

I have a point shapefile that has a 'rank' attribute with numbers between 0-100. I need to calculate the sum of this value for points within a 10km circular moving window anywhere within my area of interest. The result would be a raster, where each pixel represents the sum value of the ranks taken from all point features within a 10km radius. In ArcGIS Desktop, I could do this using the Point Statistics tool.

Is there a way of doing this in QGIS?

Comment: does [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/49899/55203) do what you're after? It's using **Heatmap (Kernel Density Estimation)** with a uniform kernel radius 10km and a weighting using the rank field.

Comment: I've added [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/292646/55203) to update it to QGIS 3